Getting dropdown list value on change using addEventListener
I am trying to get a dropdown selected value on change event. Unfortunately I did not get value selected. The following output result. If you click the dropdownlist again then it will get value correctly.
First Click Output
You clicked on a SPAN
The innerHTML is 
The text is 
The parentNode is DIV

On Second Click the output
You clicked on a SPAN
The innerHTML is <span>Active</span>
The text is Active
The parentNode is DIV

So basically it only capture on click not on change value. If I change this line of code the following does not seem to work either
From:element.addEventListener("click", function (evt)
To: element.addEventListener("change", function (evt)
Current code:
<script>
    
    function GetdrpSelected(e, param) {
      
        var txt='You clicked on a '+e.target.nodeName+'\n';
        txt+='The innerHTML is '+e.target.innerHTML+'\n';
        txt+='The text is '+e.target.textContent+'\n';
        txt+='The parentNode is '+e.target.parentNode.nodeName+'\n';
        console.log(txt);
        
    }
    
    function attachEventListener(node) {
        const element = node;
        
        element.addEventListener("click", function (evt){
            const elemId = node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].id;
            GetdrpSelected.call(this, evt, elemId);
                 
        });
    }
    
    function initCat(){
        let wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("ard-FormField-wrapper");
        for (let i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++) {
          let formLabel = wrappers[i].childNodes[0];
          if(formLabel.innerHTML !== '' && formLabel.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf('change cat') > -1){
            attachEventListener(wrappers[i].childNodes[1]);
          }
        }
    }
    
    const ddlCat = setTimeout(initCat, 2000);
    
</script>


Please include relevant html, see [mcve].  It's quite possible the clicked span doesn't have any text/html, or may be just images/icons.    Try using e.target.innerHTML (to match the txt "innerHTML is").

This question is similar to: How to get addEventListener to work with a select tag. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AlexanderSantos given the text provided by OP: You clicked on a SPAN - I would guess it's a custom drop down rather than a select - but could be wrong.

Given the loops you appear to be jumping through (setTimeout(initCat...) it looks like you're trying to work with a third-party wrapper.  Check if the wrapper provides any events you can hook into.   Consider using event delegation instead.  change probably doesn't work if the third-party wrapper doesn't raise/trigger/fire that event - it's clearly not a select, so don't treat it like one.

I have update my question above. it seems does not capture current selected value but on click value

Please add the relevant html to your question so that we may attempt to run your code.

your event listener is set to trigger on a click event rather than a change event
Instead of using e.target.nodeName you can use e.target.value like this :
function GetdrpSelected(e) {
  let selectedValue = e.target.value;
  console.log("Selected value:", selectedValue);
}
function attachEventListener(node) {
  const element = node;
  const dropdown = element.querySelector("select"); // Assuming your dropdown is a <select> element

  dropdown.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    GetdrpSelected(evt);
  });
}

function initCat() {
  let wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("ard-FormField-wrapper");
  for (let i = 0; i < wrappers.length; i++) {
    let formLabel = wrappers[i].childNodes[0];
    if (
      formLabel.innerHTML !== "" &&
      formLabel.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf("change cat") > -1
    ) {
      attachEventListener(wrappers[i].childNodes[1]);
    }
  }
}

const ddlCat = setTimeout(initCat, 2000);


Given e.target.nodeName results in span, spans do not have a .value.   Without an [mcve] from OP, this would work if the element was a select

@fdomn-m what if we use textContent?

OP has updated their question with more details (though still not enough to reproduce the issue)
